# type of the noise: PDF+Hypothesis test

Tags: probability, matlab, hypothesis-testing

I have a 2D matrix of values. I've considered these values as a    noise. What I'm trying to do is to draw the PDF of my matrix and see    the distribution of my data. But it is not enough to say that my data    are Gaussian so I want to do the hypothesis test in order to see if    the noise is Gaussian. How could I do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A gaussian is determined by its mean value and variance. Calculate those of your set of values, it will give you a theoretical PDF. Then, look at the sum of square differences between your theoretical and numerical PDF and compare it to the integral of your data squared (a rather common indicator, it is inpired from the following norm for functions : $||f-g||_2 = \int |f-g|^2$). You can try a different PDF with different parameters if you want to, and if you have a lesser difference, go for it.

Something dazzles me, though : why do you have two dimensions (a matrix)?  Are you thinking about white (or another color of) gaussian noise? A gaussian PDF usually deals with one-dimentional data

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_white_Gaussian_noise

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colors_of_noise

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my data are an image this is why I have a matrix .I calculated the mean and the std of my matrix then I calculated the pdf using them y = pdf('normal',Matrix,mean,std) which gave me the theoretical PDF, but what is it the numerical PDF?.